# MongoDB using NodeJS api return Null why?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api

I know there is a lot of post about that but none have my problem, my tables exist, the path work to some extent but two of the request just return null and I have no idea why.
Here the request that dont work :

```
// *Get Chat Message*
router.get("/message/:MessageId",async(req, res)=>{
try{
    const message = await Message.findById(req.params.MessageId);
    res.status(200).json(message)
    } catch (err){
        res.status(500).json(err)
    }
})
// *Get All Chat Message*
router.get("/message/findAll",async(req, res)=>{
try {
    const messages = await Message.find();
    res.status(200).json(messages)
} catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
}
```

})

If need here is the rest of the file where ALL the requests work PERFECTLY so I don't know why only those two don't work.

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Post = require("../models/Post");
const User = require("../models/User");
const Chat = require("../models/Chat");
const Message = require("../models/ChatMessage");

// * Get a Chat *
router.get("/:firstUserId/:secondUserId", async(req, res) => {
    const chat = await Chat.findOne({ users: { $all: [req.params.firstUserId, req.params.secondUserId] } });
    res.status(200).json(chat);
})

// * Get every Chat of one user *
router.get("/:userId", async(req, res) => {
try{
    const chats = await Chat.find({ users: { $all: [req.params.userId]} });
    res.status(200).json(chats);
}catch(err){
    res.status(500).json(err);
}
})

// *Create Chat*
router.post("/",async(req, res)=>{
const chat = new Chat(req.body)
try {
    const savedChat = await chat.save();
    res.status(200).json(savedChat);
}catch(err){
    res.status(500).json(err)
}
})

// *Delete Chat*
router.delete("/:firstUserId/:secondUserId",async(req, res)=>{
const chat = await Chat.findOne({ users: { $all: [req.params.firstUserId, req.params.secondUserId] } });
try{
    chat.deleteOne();
    res.status(200).json("The chat has been delete successfully.")
    } catch (err){
        res.status(500).json(err)
    }
})
// *Put Chat Message*
router.put("/message",async(req, res)=>{
const newMessage = new Message(req.body)
try {
    const savedMessage = await newMessage.save();
    res.status(200).json(savedMessage)
} catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err)
}
})
```

The schema name and parameter of the database are the same so I don't know why it doesn't work. It still returns null even if I erase the two that don't work, it only returns an error if I delete the whole file.

Here is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ChatMessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
conversationId: {
  type: String,
  required: true
},
userId: {
  type: String,
  required: true
},
content: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  max: 5000
},
state: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
},
{ timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("chat_message", ChatMessageSchema,"chat_messages");
```

The table
[image: MongoDb Table]
Request done in Postman
[image: PostMan Requests]

Comment: if you console something inside these two routers. can the console logs?

Comment: If it console then there will be two problems.
1. Your query is in process and res is returned before mongo query (console the returned mongo db instance).
2. There is no document exist in your db. (you can see for that id you passed in params in mongo db compass or other gui tool OR using CLI commands.)

Comment: @AliFaiz it exist in mongo i done my research by copying the id directly from mongo, and no nothing is printed from console only the message telling me ive called the api (that i also got from other route that is working) that's why i don't get why it dont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly found the error.

The problem is that for express `/message` and `/message/:MessageId` were on the same path.

`/findAll` still does not work but I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

to get all document use

```
Model.find({});
```

and for single try the following

```
Model.findOne({_id: <id>})
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error , btw sorry but It was not "undefined" but null, tell me if you need postmal result of mongodb tables with screen

Comment: yeah sure you can share.

Comment: done ive added them at the end.